# Linking fonts to @font-face through HTML?

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face

I have an assignment in university which revolves around not editing anything in the HTML-code and only the CSS-code.

I see that my teacher has used the `<link>` element with something regarding fonts. I just want to make sure if I can use anything from that element to apply a font to the webpage through `@font-face`. He has not attached any .OTF files it is therefore that I am asking.

The code:

```
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link
    href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Barlow+Condensed:wght@300&family=Barlow+Semi+Condensed:wght@300;700&display=swap"
    rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Bungee+Outline&family=Bungee+Shade&display=swap"
    rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: Use `@import` in CSS instead!

Comment: How should I then use the imported font on e.g. headers?

Comment: The same way you use any other font

Comment: So:

@import {
src: url(link);
font-family: "customname";
}

And then just use the name in font-family on the headers?

Comment: `@import url(link); selector { font-family: "customname"; } `

Answer (score 1):

If those link elements are in the HTML you have been given then you can just use those fonts in your CSS without doing anything further.

Here's a simple example using one of the Bungee fonts:

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Bungee Outline', sans-serif;
  font-size: 36px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Barlow+Condensed:wght@300&family=Barlow+Semi+Condensed:wght@300;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Bungee+Outline&family=Bungee+Shade&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Crimson+Pro">
</head>

<body>
  <div>Some non-alterable HTML</div>
</body>

</html>
```